# Random sidebar/widget background

Tags: widgets, custom-background

Does anyone have a clever idea to get a random/changing background for just the widget sidebar?

Comment: Is this a theme you can edit?

Comment: Yes totally editable them. I looked around for a plugin and found some nice ones that do full page backgrounds, but don't specify areas.  I don't have the time/budget to have something special written.

Comment: Where are you pulling the images? Do you have a set of images you already know are going to be part of the randomization or are all the images user uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following code above the DOCTYPE in header.php:

```
<?php
  $bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

Now place this code within `<head>` in header.php

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
background: url(<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

The path `<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/`indicates that your random images will be stored within your theme under the directory "/images".

The original article on this technique can be found at [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/randomize-background-image).